# Authorize.NET Serialize Old Version

Tags: vb.net, serialization, deserialization, authorize.net, visual-studio-2003

I have a Website that was built by a vendor, and it is pretty vital.

the problem is that it was built using 1.1 framework and now we need it to be at least 2.0 so the host can upgrade their servers. we have been running this website as a standalone web application so that we didn't have to alter the code to use `StateServer` Session State.

now that we need to move to the new framework they also want us to use `StateServer` session state, and I have run into the issue that the Authorize.Net portion of the code is not Serializable.

**Where do I start in the Authorize.Net project to make it serializable?**

I am looking for the fastest way to get this functioning.

is there a way that I can Serialize the whole object when it is called, I am kind of thinking this is a no from what I understand of how Serialization works.

Comment: Is `Authorize.Net` a class?  If it is, have you tried marking the class with the `<Serializable()>` attribute?

Comment: it is separate project with several classes and VB Files in it. my next step is to try and change the VB files by adding `<Serializable()>` to some of them in the hopes that it is as simple as that, and that I don't have to do a massive overhaul to make it serializable.  I am not looking forward to having to change this Site too much if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was a simple issue, and I was really stressed about it, but it turned out I just had to add `<Serializable()>`  to the Class Declaration of each class  so it looked something like

```
 <Serializable()> Public Class ANet
```

Just like Tim said.